# Why does Twitter API return the error 'If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level?'

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twitter-api-v2, twitter-api-v1

I'm trying to use this function with Python

```
def create_thread(message_text, media_ids=None):
    tweets = [message_text[i:i + 280] for i in range(0, len(message_text), 280)]
    if media_ids:
        response = client_v1.update_status(status=tweets[0], media_ids=media_ids)
    else:
        response = client_v2.create_tweet(text=tweets[0])
    for tweet in tweets[1:]:
        response = client_v2.create_tweet(text=tweet, reply_settings={'reply': {'id': response.id}})
    return response
```

I Have Elevated Access in Twitter and I pay for the Basic plan, which includes the access that I am trying to use in Twitter API V2 and V1.1, but when I try to use this function, it returns the error:

response = client_v1.update_status(status=tweets[0], media_ids=media_ids)
tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have access to Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve

[Table of benefits of basic plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvRcr.png)

The function tweets a post with an image and a caption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UPDATE_STATUS` in api v1.1 is deprecated and they didnt updated the documentation and the table of benefits for Free/ basic / premium plan.

The solution: Change update_status function to create tweet

Before:

```
response = client_v1.update_status(status=tweets[0], media_ids=media_ids)
```

Correct:

```
response = client_v2.create_tweet(text=tweets[0], media_ids=media_ids)
```

the documentation says that create tweet doesn't work with `media_ids`, but it worked. Also, I have been trying `update_status` with the text being sent as `Status=tweets[0]`, but must be exchanged to `text=tweets[0]`

Comment: With free access, it is not even possible to post a simple tweet? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76419375/5029509

Comment: Wow, it worked in my case, so basically you have to now, upload_media by API v 1.1 and create_tweet by API 2.0. Twitter is a maze.